# Create ArrayList where next element is bigger than previous by a certain number dynamically

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I need to create an `ArrayList<Float>()` where each next element of list must be bigger from previous by a certain number. `the last element of array always = 100f` but the size can change. For example,  `if size = 5`,

I need something like this `ArrayList<Float> list = arrayOf(20f, 40f,60f,80f,100f)`. But the problem is that I don't know how many elements I will have and need to do everything dynamically. 
Here is my list

```
 var size= 5
 var progress= 100/size.toFloat()

 list = ArrayList<Float>()
          for (i in 0 until size) {
            list.add(progress)
        }
```

and here I am trying to add next and previous elements

```
for (i in 0 until list.size) {
            val curr = list[i]
            val next = list[(i + prog).toInt()]
           }
```

But don't know how to add it to `ArrayList`
Please, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the values are distributed evenly.
In this case, this is simple mathmatics:

Array[index] = index * step = index * (100 / size)

```kotlin
val max = 100
val size = 7

val step = max / size.toFloat()
val list = ArrayList<Float>(size)
for (i in 0 until size) {
   list.add(step * (i+1))
}

// or better with kotlin collections
val klist = List(size) { index -> step * (index + 1) }
```